# How can we change the locale of the client side error page in laravel based on the auth locale and without auth locale?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-localization

I have to change the language of the page like 404,403 etc in laravel with the locale. This means if the auth has a locale then the locale is the user's locale otherwise default locale.

I have tried this in my handler.php file in the Exception folder.
The file path is: App\Exceptions\Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
    {
        if (auth()->user()) {
            app()->setLocale(auth()->user()->locale);
        }else if(!auth()->user() && $request->session('locale')) {
            app()->setLocale(session('locale'));
        }else{
            app()->setLocale(config('app.locale'));
        }

        if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

After I did this all worked properly but when try to type the route that doesn't exists it shows:=> This page isn’t working example. the test is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Try putting a try catch inside the `render` method of  `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` and log the error

Comment: @ArunAS can you tell me how to do it cause I'm trying it but didn't get anything.

Comment: `public function render($request, Throwable $e){ try{ /** Your code */ }catch(\Throwable $th){logger()->error($th);}}`

Comment: @ArunAS It's working for defined route but when I try to use undefined route it throw 500 error.

Comment: try putting the try catch and check laravel.log to find the error, that is what I meant. It won't fix the issue, it will instead help you find the cause

Comment: @ArunAS problem is that I can't get auth in that part. It return null when I try to dump and die. Do you have any idea about how can I get auth?